# strpos checks other special character rather than dot

Tags: php

I got the following php code:

```
$name = 'Test. I Am-trd-yr-d-dq .mmmm';

if (strpos($name, '.') !== false) {
    preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', ' ', substr($name, 0, 40)));
} else {
    preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', substr($name, 0, 40)));
}
```

What I am trying to do is that if the string contains`.` dot it should just replace it as a `''` else if it contains like `-` or `/` it should replace it as `' '` spacw, but currently its just doing `Test  I Am trd yr d dq  mmmm` which it changes the dot to ' ' so i got 2 spaces.

The expected result should be `Test I Am trd yr d dq mmmm`

Comment: format your question and add the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). Then read about [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). It can also do what you need, it runs faster and the code is much cleaner:

```
$name = 'Test. I Am-trd-yr-d-dq .mmmm';

$changed = str_replace(
    array('.', '-', '/'),     // replace each of these items...
    array('',  ' ', ' '),     // ... with the corresponding item from this list...
    $name                     // ... into this
);

var_dump($changed);
# string(26) "Test I Am trd yr d dq mmmm"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired in this way:

```
$name = 'Test. I Am-trd-yr-d-dq .mmmm';
$name = preg_replace('/\./', '', $name);
$name = preg_replace('/[\-]/', ' ', $name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `regex` try the following:

```
$name = 'Test. I Am-trd-yr-d-dq .mmmm';

$name = preg_replace_callback_array(
[
    '/[.]/' => function ($match) {
        return '';
    },
    '/[/-]/' => function ($match) {
        return ' ';
    }
],
$name);
```

var_dump($name);

Or you can simply use `strtr` or `str_replace`:

```
$name = 'Test. I Am-trd-yr-d-dq .mmmm';

$name = strtr($name, ['.' => '', '/' => ' ', '-' => ' ']);

var_dump($name);
```